# Unable to create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am aware this has been asked allot, and I am sorry but I honestly can't find the answer.

This is my admins table:

```
CREATE TABLE `admins` (
     `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `admin_user` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_fName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `admin_lName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the table I am trying to create to reference the admin_fname:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(
    post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        post_title varchar(50),
        post_content varchar(255),
        post_user varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (post_user) REFERENCES admins(admin_fName)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

post_user seems to have the same attributes as admin_fname, and there is data in the parent table. could any body please explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference `post_user` on column `admin_fname` on table `admins` becasue you did not defined a key on it. To answer your question directly, you must add a key on the column,

```
CREATE TABLE `admins`
(
     `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `admin_user` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_fName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `admin_lName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     KEY (admin_fName),                        -- <<== adding key
     PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

but it is not a good idea to reference into a `NON_UNIQUE` column because on the long run records may mixed for users having the same `fname`. The better design is to leave table as is. Add a column on table `posts` that reference to its primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE `admins` 
(
     `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `admin_user` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `admin_fName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `admin_lName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts
(
        post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        post_title varchar(50),
        post_content varchar(255),
        admin_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES admins(admin_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```